# CK Content Injector enabling is disabled

Tags: wysiwyg

I just installed CK Content Injector module but I cant not enable it since the checkbox is disabled. it shows missing libraries but the node.php is present in the template folder

Comment: go the libraries way perhaps then it will let you enable?